# is it possible to remove android Google Maps Marker based on Tag?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am attaching a tag to a Marker when I add it to GoogleMap like this:

```
 val icon = IconGenerator(context).makeIcon("${listing.cost}$")

        map.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(address.latitude, address.longitude))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon!!))
        ).tag = listing
```

Is it possible to remove the marker later if it matches the tag I assigned it to?

Listing is an object on the Database that I am adding to GoogleMap, and I want to remove the listing Marker when it is removed from the Database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is No. I ended up saving the Marker in a ViewModel hashMap variable that has Marker id as key, and actual Marker Object as Value.

I stored the Marker's id on a database then I get the actual Marker from the hashMap using the id as key, then remove it.